# change condition in while loop does not take effect

Tags: java, while-loop, conditional-statements

Yesterday , I wrote some code like this:

```
public class WhileTest {
private static boolean close=false;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                int i=0;
                while(!close) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("count:"+i++);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

    System.out.println("close:"+close);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    close=true;
    System.out.println("close:"+close);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    close=false;
    System.out.println("close:"+close);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    close=true;
    System.out.println("close:"+close);
    System.exit(0);
}}
```

when close set to false again, it was not print count anymore,I run javap to see if !close condition in while loop was compiled to true,and it's not ,I don't understand,can anyone help me ?

Comment: Because you forgot to declare `close ` as `volatile`

Comment: @mzeus.bolt: you're comment appears to be wrong, while alfasin's is correct. Test it. The field needs to be declared `volatile`. If he exits the outer loop, then the counting will never resume, which is what the OP desires to occur.

Comment: It will exit when the main thread calls: `System.exit(0);`

Comment: problem solved,thanks all ! now I have another question,can anyone tells me what the meaning of "OP" in Hovercraft's comment?@Hovercraft Full Of Eels @alfasin

Comment: OP can mean "original poster" (you) or "original post" (your main question).

Comment: I think it means operator in the first place,ha ha,thanks. @Hovercraft Full Of Eels